# Why is this Low Variable in a snippet not parsing?

Tags: parse-order, snippets, low-variables

I have a snippet that I use on nearly every page of a site. I need to give the admins some control in the fallback source of an image in that snippet. Now I know there is a parse order issue here as it works fine when dropped directly into the template, I am just wondering if there is a workaround?

```
    {exp:switchee variable="{segment_1}/{segment_2}" parse="inward"}    
    {case value="events/{segment_2}"}
        {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_fallback_banner"}
            {exp:ce_img:pair src="{event_masthead}" height="270" min_width="1600" max_width="1600" fallback_src="{url}" crop="yes" allow_scale_larger="yes" filter="brightness,-80|grayscale|colorize,80,39,9,10"}style="background:url('{made}') no-repeat 50% 0; height: 270px;"
            {/exp:ce_img:pair}
        {/exp:low_variables:parse}
    {/case}     
    {case value="member-directory/{segment_2}"}
        {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_fallback_banner"}
            {member_photo_gallery limit="1"}
                {exp:ce_img:pair src="{url}" height="270" min_width="1600" max_width="1600" fallback_src="{lv_fallback_banner}" crop="yes" allow_scale_larger="yes" filter="brightness,-80|grayscale|colorize,80,39,9,10"}style="background:url('{made}') no-repeat 50% 0; height: 270px;"
                {/exp:ce_img:pair}
            {/member_photo_gallery}
        {/exp:low_variables:parse}      
    {/case}     
    {case default="yes"}
        {exp:low_variables:parse var="lv_fallback_banner"}
            {exp:ce_img:pair src="{masthead}" height="270" min_width="1600" max_width="1600" fallback_src="{url}" crop="yes" allow_scale_larger="yes" filter="brightness,-80|grayscale|colorize,80,39,9,10"}style="background:url('{made}') no-repeat 50% 0; height: 270px;"
            {/exp:ce_img:pair}
        {/exp:low_variables:parse}
    {/case}                 
{/exp:switchee}
```

Comment: What is your low variable set for parsing? early or late? have you tried changing to exp:low_variables:pair instead of parse?

Comment: It is set to early parsing. I have also tried changing to pair. No luck yet. When I have a valid SRC variable the image parses as expected, but when the {masthead} field is empty the fallback is not working. I will update the origial post with my current snippet.

Comment: You're using the tag-syntax instead of the variable-syntax here. This means early/late parsing is irrelevant, as that only applies to the variable syntax: early parsing = before tags, late parsing = after tags. Also, switching between the :pair and :parse tags only makes a difference when having both single :parse tags and paired :parse tags in 1 template. That can cause conflicts, so it's recommended to use :single when using a single tag, and :pair when using a tag pair.

Comment: Understood. The issue then is how can I get your Low Variables (with P&T Assets) to output a URL that CE-Image can parse? {lv_fallback_banner} outputs "{filedir_6}example.jpg"

Comment: What if you use `{exp:ce_img:pair ... fallback_src="{exp:low_variables:single var='lv_fallback_banner'}" ... parse="inward"}` as the CI Image opening tag. Make sure everything is on a single line. Having the :parse tag in a pair for a variable that needs extra processing (like Assets does with the `{filedir_x}` vars), only works for single tags at the moment.

Comment: Thats done it. If you make this an answer I will accept it as the approved answer. Thanks Low!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `lv_fallback_banner` is an Assets variable type, which stores the data like this: `{filedir_x}my-image.jpg`. To parse the filedir-variable, you need to use the `{exp:low_variables:single}` tag, so Assets gets called and can process it (instead of just dumping the variable content in the template).

In this case, it will always return the parsed variable content, **not** the tagdata inside the `:parse` tag, so the `ce_img` tag will be lost. To solve, use the `:single` tag inside the `ce_img` tag's parameter:

```
{exp:ce_img:pair ... fallback_src="{exp:low_variables:single var='lv_fallback_banner'}" ... parse="inward"}
```

Also make sure everything is on a single line, or EE's template parser may choke.

Answer (score 6):

Your first conditional statement is an *advanced conditional* (since it includes an `AND` clause), which means that *both* of your `{preload_replace}` variables are being called every time. Since subsequent `{preload_replace}` calls for the same variable are ignored, I'd guess that you're ending up with `{event_masthead}` every time, is that right?

Comment: If this is correct, then I would recommend using Croxtons IfElse plugin and parse inwards - that should fix it for you.

Comment: Can't really comment on Low Variables... so just adding to what's been said...

Derek is spot on. As CreateSean said [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) add-on could remedy that, e.g. wrap the whole conditional in `{exp:ifelse parse="inward"}...{/exp:ifelse}`. However, since this is a SN note IfElse can't be nested. If you use IfElse outside, you may want to use [Switchee beta](https://github.com/croxton/Switchee/tree/develop) instead. ([Switchee on Devot-ee here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee).)

Answer (score 1):

To follow-up on what Tyssen said:
If you don't want to use a third-party plugin ( like switchee or ifelse ) you could do it with standard EE. However Tyssen's conditionals are still being considered advanced conditionals, so they won't solve your problem.

This should work though:

```
{if segment_1 == 'events'}
    {if segment_2 == ''}
        {preload_replace:group='event_'}
    {/if}
{/if}
{if segment_1 != 'events'}
    {if segment_2 != ''}
        {preload_replace:group=''}
    {if}
{/if}
```

More on conditionals:
http://userguides.ellislab.com/expressionengine/templates/globals/conditionals.html

Answer (score -1):

To avoid using an advanced conditional and not necessarily having to use IfElse or Switchee (both of which are great by the way), you could do this instead:

```
{if segment_1 == 'events' AND segment_2 == ''}
    {preload_replace:group='event_'}
{/if}
{if segment_1 != 'events' AND segment_2 != ''}
    {preload_replace:group=''}
{/if}
```

That's no longer an advanced conditional because there's no if:else.

Comment: I think these are advanced conditionals http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html

Comment: Oops, yeah, sorry, you're right. Having an operator in there makes it advanced anyway.